# form validation exception not catching by Exception in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In laravel5, I have catching all error at `app/Exceptions/Handler@render` function and it was working fine.
code given below,

```
     public function render($request, Exception $e) {
        $error_response['error'] = array(
            'code' => NULL,
            'message' => NULL,
            'debug' => NULL
        );
        if ($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 422) {
            $error_response['error']['code'] = 422;
            $error_response['error']['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $error_response['error']['debug'] = null;
            return new JsonResponse($error_response, 422);
        } 
 }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

But in laravel5.1,When form validation failes,it throws error message with `422`exception. but it is not catching from  `app/Exceptions/Handler@render`  but working fine with `abort(422)`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Form Request fails to validate your data it fires the `failedValidation(Validator $validator)` method that throws `HttpResponseException` with a fresh Redirect Response, but not `HttpException`. This exception is caught via Laravel Router in its `run(Request $request)` method and that fetches the response and fires it. So you don't have any chance to handle it via your Exceptions Handler.

But if you want to change this behaviour you can overwrite `failedValidation` method in your Abstract Request or any other Request class and throw your own exception that you will handle in the Handler.

Or you can just overwrite `response(array $errors)` and create you own response that will be proceed by the Router automatically.

Comment: how can I or where should I overwrite `failedValidation` method?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen if you want to have this behaviour for every FormRequest, you have to do it in your `abstract Request` class (/app/Http/Requests/Request). If you want to have it for the certain Request, you have to overwrite it right in it.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch simply by doing

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {
    if($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Laravel 5.4 - just remember to add your use statement to the top of the `Handler` class: ```use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;``` (I initially forgot it!)

Comment: Thanks.. Worked in Laravel 5.8 too