# Laravel throw ValidationException but not hitting destroy method's catch block?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return a custom exception message using Laravel's `ValidationException` class. I have it successfully working in the following example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, CurrencyValidatorArrays::$store);
    try {
        $this->currenciesInstance->createOrUpdateCurrency($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('currencies.index')
        ->with('success', 'Successfully created currency');
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return redirect()->route('currencies.create')
        ->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

where the exception is thrown from within `createOrUpdateCurrency()`

```
    if(Currency::where('position', $data['position'])->where('id', '!=', $id)->exists()) {

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'error' => ['Position value is already taken']
         ]);
    }
```

This then passes the exception message back to my view for display.

However, I am trying to implement this somewhere else when trying to delete a company I am checking that no users exist first:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {

            $this->companiesInstance->deleteCompany($id);

            return redirect()->route('companies.index')
            ->with('success', 'Successfully deleted company');

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return redirect()->route('companies.index')
            ->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Inside of `deleteCompany()`:

```
$company = Company::find($id);
if($company->users()->exists()){
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'error' => ['Position value is already taken']
     ]);
}
```

For some reason this doesn't hit my catch block from the main destroy method,if I change the exception type to `ValidationException` from `Exception` I can access and see the exception object but not in the way I can in the `Store()` methods version. Any ideas what is going on here?

UPDATE:

So I have a some what of a workaround:

To get by the exception type issue I used:

```
catch (ValidationException | Exception $e) { ...
```

But that still does not help when accessing the exception messages as when it's of type ValidationException the default constructor validation message is returned from `getMessage()` and not my specified one.

Comment: Hi, the out-of-the-box ValidationException instance from Laravel, I noticed, does not allow you enough time to catch the exception as it redirects before you can do anything. Have a look at the link below. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217541/form-validation-exception-not-catching-by-exception-in-laravel-5-1/31218956#31218956

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 handles exceptions a bit differently. You can read it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php).

Coming back to your code, you have to try and catch object of Throwable instead of Exception.

```
try
{
   // Code that may throw an Exception or Error.
}
catch (Throwable $t)
{
   // Code that handles the error
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed the issue, the main problem is that ValidationException can be handled fine as a standard Exception in store but not destroy(). :(

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown by your code inside deleteCompany()? Can you try to create the exception and dump it before you actually throw the exception?